# Firebase Test Lab instrumented test for test method annotated by size

Tags: android, firebase, android-testing, firebase-test-lab, gradle-android-test-plugi

In my project I am using the following commands to generate my app APK and instrumented test APK.

```
./gradlew :app:assembleDebug
./gradlew :app:assembleDebugAndroidTest
```

Using the generated files I am triggering a test in Test Lab using gcloud, which works without problems.

Now, I want to have annotations for the test size (small, medium, large), so only a subset of tests can be triggered in Test Lab, based on the test annotations.

Can it be done or is there a different approach to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using the `--test-targets` flag. It supports the same options as the `-e` flag for [AndroidJUnitRunner](https://developers.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner).

If you use the `SmallTest`, `MediumTest`, `LargeTest` annotations from `android.support.test.filters` package you can e.g. only run the small test the following way:

```
gcloud firebase test android run --test-targets "size small" <your other flags>
```

Custom annotations are supported too:

```
gcloud firebase test android run --test-targets "annotation com.example.MyAnnotation
```

For more options, take a look at the [gcloud documentation for this command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run#--test-targets).